# blender internal nodes: all my materials are coming out mixed with pink

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

im having a hard time understand how these nodes work. i DO have the material activate in BI and not cycles but it still comes out pink. furthermore the textures are only partly pink. using texture coordinates doenst help

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you change the Red and Blue settings in the Mix Node does that change the Pink? What outcome did you want?

Comment: @rob im following this tutorial but using the node setup for an object (skydome) instead of the world background. changing the red and blue around did nothing

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Invert Normal" in the Material Node?

Comment: Check if shader has missing images in "Texture" tab. Pink is usually a sign of missing files

Comment: @SergeL yeah there is an issue with the texture it appears because when i change the default pink colour for both textures it responds. however i look at my setup and i dont see anything wrong? https://i.imgur.com/nXEhefw.png